# How increase NumericUpDown decimal

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, numericupdown

How increase NumericUpDown decimal  this way:

```
0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03...
```

and not

```
1.00, 2.00, 3.00, 4.00, 5.00...
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the [`Increment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment) property:

```
numericUpDown1.Increment = 0.01m;
```

You can also set this in the property window of the NumericUpDown control in the Windows Forms Designer.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the [`Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment(v=vs.110).aspx) property to be `0.01`